# "Существенных изменений (не) заметно". Как писать НЕ?

Tags: орфография, частица-не

У Розенталя:
Слитно или раздельно пишутся с НЕ так называемые предикативные наречия на **-о** (слова категории состояния) типа **нетрудно видеть – не трудно видеть**:
при утверждении они пишутся слитно, при отрицании – раздельно.

Далее приводятся примеры:
а) неважно, что он о нас думает; не опасно, что в лечении сделан небольшой перерыв.

А в примечании 2:
Различается написание с НЕ безлично-предикативных слов на **-о** и созвучных с ними кратких прилагательных и наречий:

```
Существенных изменений не заметно. Пятно незаметно. Подал знак незаметно.
```

Но разве предикативные наречия на **-о** (слова категории состояния) и безлично-предикативные слова на **-о** — это не одно и то же?
(Если читать по ссылке: http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook107/01/part-112.htm.)

Следовательно, в предложениях

```
 Существенных изменений (не) заметно. Нам будет (не) весело. Было (не) тепло.
```

НЕ  может писаться слитно и раздельно: при утверждении они пишутся слитно, при отрицании — раздельно.

*Мне сделалось неприятно и неловко (Писем.).*
Этот пример приводит Валгина (по указанной выше ссылке) — "Наиболее четки и определенны синтаксические признаки безлично-предикативных слов".

То есть в этом предложении *неприятно* и *неловко* — безлично-предикативные слова и (по примечанию 2 Розенталя) должны писаться с НЕ раздельно?

Comment: Существенных изменений не замечено (не видно). Изменения незаметны (= несущественны).

Answer (score 1):

> А следовательно в предложении:
>
> *Существенных изменений (не) заметно.*  НЕ может писаться слитно и раздельно: при утверждении они пишутся слитно, при отрицании –
>   раздельно.

В рамках русского языка Вы не можете это предложение считать утвердительным. Чтобы сделать его утвердительным, Вам нужно заменить родительный падеж именительным: *существенные изменения произошли незаметно* или *[в этом случае даже] существенные изменения незаметны*.

Answer (score 1):

**Существенных изменений не заметно.** Это раздельное написание НЕ с предикативным наречием.

Если посмотреть реальные тексты для ***не заметно/незаметно***, то они соответствуют правилу Розенталя, то есть НЕ пишется раздельно с предикативными наречиями, а слитно с наречиями обстоятельственными (и краткими прилагательными).

По смыслу же эти формы (отрицание и утверждение) **практически не различаются**, выбор грамматический, а не смысловой.

Посмотрим другие примеры:

**Нам будет не весело** (веселья не будет). **На будет невесело** (грустно)  Здесь формы различаются по смыслу, авторский выбор.

**Было не тепло.** Предложение неестественное,  реально:  было совсем не тепло, как мы ожидали.  Но написание НЕ всегда раздельное. Прилагательное ***нетеплый*** практически не  встречается при градации признака.: горячий ― не горячий ―  теплый ― не холодный ― холодный.

**Мне сделалось неприятно и неловко.** Здесь безличный глагол-связка, а именная часть выражена обстоятельственными, а не предикативными наречиями.